# Using "no" to emphasize a negative statement

Tags: prepositions, negation, inversion, style

We say something like

> He is no ordinary human being.

This phrasing gives the negative more emphasis than usually given by negation device "not"

> He is not an ordinary human being.

It is this added emphasis that I am trying to induce in the following sentence, but I have some doubts as to the usage of "no" after the verb "makes"

> Her mastery of French makes her no typical member of the laity.

May I have some feedback on the sentence, please?

Thank you.

PS: And if the sentence is Ok, would the following sound better:

> Her mastery of French makes **of** her no typical member of the laity.

Comment: Absolutely okay *to me!* Just I'd use *'mastery **on**'*...

Comment: Thank you, I respectfully disagree with your choice of preposition.                   https://books.google.com/books?id=iUVhMWQBc3sC&pg=PA351&dq=mastery+of+the+language&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBWoVChMI_YzLvbXzyAIVSuQmCh1mmQ0U#v=onepage&q=mastery%20of%20the%20language&f=false

Comment: Never mind! Go on. But I know that [students must achieve **mastery on** each test before going on to the next topic or unit](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=TjDIqrzfYaMC&pg=PA740&dq=%22mastery+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22mastery%20on%22&f=false)

Comment: @MaulikV [***of***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/of) - 6. with (something specified) as object, goal, etc."   ⇒ a reader **of** books"

Comment: @user3169 wait, this forms a very good question for me! Putting!

Comment: *Her mastery of French makes her no typical member of the laity.* The **of** isn't required as the sentence stands by itself and conveys the meaning intended to be conveyed.

Comment: If you keep the "of", the sentence means, "Due to her recent mastery of French, she has become an atypical member of the laity."

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong grammatically with the following sentence:

Her mastery of French makes her no typical member of the laity.

On the other hand, the other sentence with the use of the phrasal verb "make of" doesn't sound correct in the sentence as someone  makes something/someone of, not something makes someone/something of.  You use the phrasal verb to express your opinion about or how you understand someone/something.

Answer (score 0):

As a native US English speaker, I think the intended meaning (emphasizing the negative) comes across better if you say

> Her mastery of French makes her no ordinary member of the laity.